# "RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback" When calling the function

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot that need to send message to a channel whenever there is a new record. But when i call the `test()` it showed me `C:\Users\crayx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\CovidBotFinal.py:79: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'test' was never awaited test() RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`. How does this happen ? My logic is whenever I retrieve a new record, I will publish it to my discord channel.

My code :

```
import discord
import random
import time
import asyncio
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
import time
import re


#demolist to run at first time
listposts=[]

listView = None
token = 'xxx'

client = discord.Client()


chrome_path = r"C:\Users\crayx\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
#driver.get ("https://covid-19.moh.gov.my/terkini")
driver.get ("C:/Users/crayx/Desktop/testweb.html")

class Loop(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id_manager):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id_manager = int(id_manager)

    async def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                driver.refresh()
                #time.sleep(3)
                posts = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="g-mainbar"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div""")
                #print(posts.text)
                listposts.append(posts.text)

                time.sleep(5)
                global listView
                if listposts != 0 and listposts != listView:
                    listView = listposts.copy()
                    print(listView)
                    await test()

                listposts.clear()
                #print(listposts)

            except:
                continue
        
async def test():
    channel = client.get_channel(xxx)
    await channel.send(listView[0])



def main():
    print("Scraping Process Started")
    thread_id = ("0")
    led_index = 0
    thread_list = list()
    for objs in thread_id:
        thread = Loop(led_index)
        thread_list.append(thread)
        led_index += 1
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if listposts != 0:
        out = []
        for v in listView:
            regex_list = re.findall(r"^(.*?\(.*?\))\n", v.replace('.\n', '\n').replace('.', ':'), flags=re.M)
            for g in regex_list:
                out.append(g.split(":")[0])


    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("-selangor"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[1])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")


    if message.content.startswith("-kl"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[2])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-johor"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[3])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-sabah"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[4])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-sarawak"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[5])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-negeri sembilan"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[6])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-kedah"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[7])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-penang"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[8])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-kelantan"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[9])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-perak"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[10])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-melaka"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[11])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-pahang"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[12])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-terengganu"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[13])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-labuan"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[14])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-putrajaya"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[15])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-perlis"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(out[0] + "\n" + out[16])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")

    if message.content.startswith("-malaysia"):
        if len(listView) != 0:
            await message.channel.send(listView[0])
        else:
            await message.channel.send(
                "I'm still updating my information. Please try again in a few seconds.")



    else:
        pass

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("BOT IS RUNNING")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


client.run(token)
```

Comment: Please do not edit questions in such a way as to invalidate existing answers. If you encounter a new problem as part of applying answers to your code, ask a new question.

Comment: Note that there isn't much point mixing threading and asyncio. Both do roughly the same but in different ways; mixing the two just needlessly complicates things without much benefit.

Answer (score 0):

`test` is an asynchronous function, so you need to await it.

```
            if listposts != 0 and listposts != listView:
                listView = listposts.copy()
                print(listView)
                await test()
```

Comment: thanks for ur response, but it showing me `SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
`

Comment: ah yeah sorry for that, should've made that clear, you then also need to convert your run function to be asynchronous, so `async def run(self):`

Comment: I tried to put my run function as async but it still showing `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop.run' was never awaited
  self.run()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: when you call a asynchronous function, you always need to await it, so you need to await the run function too.

Comment: I just update my question with a full code. Can you guide me where should I await my `run`  function ? thanks

Comment: I think the naming of the function clashes with something else, try re-naming that function

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Loop(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id_manager):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id_manager = int(id_manager)

    async def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                driver.refresh()
                #time.sleep(3)
                posts = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="g-mainbar"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div""")
                #print(posts.text)
                listposts.append(posts.text)

                time.sleep(5)
                global listView
                if listposts != 0 and listposts != listView:
                    listView = listposts.copy()
                    print(listView)
                    await test()

                listposts.clear()
                #print(listposts)

            except:
                continue

async def test():
    channel = client.get_channel(channelId)
    await channel.send(listView[0])
```

test is an async function so you have to await it and because you can only use async functions inside of async function run also has to be an async function

Comment: I tried to put my run function as async but it still showing me `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Loop.run' was never awaited
  self.run()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: when you call the run function you have to await that one as well

Comment: where should I await my run function ? sorry if I asked a dumb question, I cant figured out where should i await my `run`